# How can I create a user-password login webpage using python bottle

Tags: python

when I run the following code it ended in Import error:cannot import name route
Can anyone help me??

```
from bottle import route, run

@route('/:name')
def index(name='World'):
    return '<b>Hello %s!</b>' % name

run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

Comment: Don't create user-password login pages. Please use OpenID instead. I'm tired of having 500 passwords to remember.

Comment: +1. @Omnifarious I have too many passwords

Comment: Also I might point out did you name your script bottle.py?

Comment: A user-password login page may be just fine depending on the purpose and audience of his webpage.

Answer (score 1):

That example program is awful. It contains a cross-site scripting attack.

My guess is that you named the file you put your program in `bottle.py`. Either that or you haven't installed bottle.

Comment: Did you not read the comments on my post? It was merely an example